# Extract a string from text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I want to extract set of strings from a medium sized text only file (say test.txt) through batch in windows. so when i do this :

```
findstr  "ssh-rsa" test.txt >test.txt
```

i get the same test.txt as output. How to resolve the problem ?

**Edit 1 :** This is the [link of file at github](https://github.com/gitsubham/codesnippets/blob/master/rsa_search.txt) and i need to search text at `line 522` or more specifically `75:d9:e3:5b:c8:17:ef:72:92:78:e5:8e:0c:82:7e:e1`

**Edit 2 :** From external (mutable) source:

```
ci-info: ssh-rsa c1:e8:5c:66:c2:b0:6d:68:a7:94:fd:05:4a:26:79:b2 - ec2_key_us-west-1

ec2:
ec2: #############################################################
ec2: -----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: 1024 7a:e8:09:5e:0b:f4:cc:d5:75:38:60:bf:29:11:81:04 root@ip-10-0-0-55 (DSA)
ec2: 256 e6:25:23:8f:75:b4:c9:50:99:71:b7:11:4f:c6:40:52 root@ip-10-0-0-55 (ECDSA)
ec2: 2048 f2:df:0b:0d:f2:62:ab:c0:65:cf:65:04:1f:7d:9b:8a (RSA1)
ec2: 2048 75:d9:e3:5b:c8:17:ef:72:92:78:e5:8e:0c:82:7e:e1 root@ip-10-0-0-55 (RSA)
ec2: -----END SSH HOST KEY FINGERPRINTS-----
ec2: #############################################################
-----BEGIN SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
```

Line 522 is the second starting "ec2: 2048" - posted codesection is lines 514..525

Comment: Your question is way too vague to even hazard an answer. What do you mean by a "medium sized" file (title) or "long file" (narrative)? What else can you reveal about this file? Are there some characters that will definitely not appear in the file? Is this the only occurrence of the pattern "ssh-rsa" followed by 12 characters (always 12?) Does the file contain non-printable characters, or characters that have special meaning to `cmd` like ()*%!+"';~ How do you propose to "insert newline character arbitrarily"? Can you use freeware utilities like `SED`?

Comment: @rojo as the question states, i am looking for windows solution not shell !

Comment: i am not sure about the type of characters that will appear in the file as it is system log of an EC2 instance. the exact string required will be of this form,  `ssh-rsa c1:e8:5c:66:c2:b0:6d:68:a7:94:fd:05:4a:26:79:b2`, as @dbenham said in his answer i cant insert the newline arbitarily, so not going to pursue that option. It was a bad idea anyways ! no i cant use any firmware utilities.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not making sense. First you say your source file does not contain line feeds, but you post an example file that is full of line feeds and say you need to search at line 522. You also do not adequately describe the rules for the string you are looking for.

Comment: If you give a precise description of how to identify the string you want, then perhaps someone can help. Just stating the result for one specific example is no good - if you know the result, then why search? You need to state precise generalized rules on how to identify the string for all cases.

Comment: initially i was taking the console output of the EC2 instance in json format (by default) later when i searched a bit more then i found that i can generate the output in table format also, so i did that and the file that i got is posted at gihub @dbenham and also the format of rsa key is unknown to me, but the number of characters are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting newlines is not an option because you first need to search to make sure you don't break up the string you are trying to find - catch 22.

As long as the file is less than 2 gigabytes in size, then you can use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs regular expression search and replace on text files. REPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

You haven't stated what your exact search term is, so I will just search for `ssh-rsa xx:nn:nn:nn`. I use the `\JMATCH` option to put each match on a new line, and discard everything that does not match.

```
jrepl "ssh-rsa [a-z][a-z]:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d" "$0" /jmatch /f test.txt /o result.txt
```

If you want to overwrite the original file, then

```
jrepl "ssh-rsa [a-z][a-z]:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d" "$0" /jmatch /f test.txt /o -
```

If used in a batch script, don't forget to use `call jrepl ...`, since JREPL is also a batch script.

Comment: the exact string required will be of this form, `ssh-rsa c1:e8:5c:66:c2:b0:6d:68:a7:94:fd:05:4a:26:79:b2`  and can you please give me link for REPL.BAT

Comment: another sample search string is `ssh-rsa 9a:36:b8:0a:2c:9a:0c:99:49:48:72:bd:dd:31:2d:df`.  so it can be any combination of alphabets and digits, but the size is fixed though! and i saw the REPL.BAT , it was just below the JREPL.BAT.

Comment: also my requirement compels me to use only pure batch files so can you please propose a solution with all the other facts in mind as stated in comments above

Comment: This is the link of file at github [https://github.com/gitsubham/codesnippets/blob/master/rsa_search.txt] and i need to search text at line 522 or more specifically `75:d9:e3:5b:c8:17:ef:72:92:78:e5:8e:0c:82:7e:e1`

Comment: @SubhamTripathi - REPL.BAT does not have the needed features. I abandoned development of REPL.BAT in favor of JREPL.BAT. Native batch commands cannot reasonably search a large file that does not contain newlines because batch cannot process strings longer than 8191 bytes long. A solution could be written using FC in binary mode by searching one byte at a time, but it would be totally impractical and slow - really only good as an academic exercise.

Comment: i have found a way to insert newlines in the file, it is present at github

Answer (score 0):

Compelling question: how-to parse a text file which is **not** *well-structured*. There's my *pure batch* solution, given despite of Magoo's cogent warning:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
:: define a keyword
set "keyword=ssh-rsa"
:: create output file
type nul>testtest.txt
:: process input file line by line  
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%F in ('findstr /I "%keyword%" test.txt') do ( 
  call :fooProc "%keyword%" "%%~F"
)
:: show result
type testtest.txt
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:: Procedure seeks for %~1 keyword in %~2 line and
:: for each found keyword writes the pair 'keyword value' 
:: to given output file, where 'value' = word next to 'keyword'.
:: Structure of 'line' supplied considered not well defined:
:: there could appear 0..n irrelevant words between
:: near-by 'keyword value' pairs and/or afore of first one
:: and/or by last one.
:: Suppose no presence of non-printable characters, or characters
:: with special meaning to batch processing (echo, call, if, ...)
:: like !, % or |, >, >>, < redirectors in the 'line' supplied.  
:fooProc
  SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  set "foo=%~2"
:fooLoop
  for /F "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%G in ("!foo!") do ( 
    if /I "%%~G"=="%~1" (
      @echo %%G %%H>>testtest.txt
      set "foo= %%I"
    ) else (
      @rem echo         forgotten %%G
      set "foo=%%H %%I"
    )
  )
  if not "!foo!"==" " goto :fooLoop
  ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
:: end fooProc
```

Trial `test.txt` file used for testing  (with or without trailing `CrLf`):

```
ssh-rsa ab:23:45:01 abc ssh-rsa ab:23:45:02 qwe rtz ssh-rsa ab:23:45:03 sedr fdert ssh-rsa ab:23:45:04 ssh-rsa ab:23:45:05 end01 end02 end03
2ndline ssh-rsa cd:23:45:21 abc 222 SSH-RSA cd:23:45:22 qwe rtz ssh-rsa cd:23:45:23 sedr fdert SSH-RSA cd:23:45:24 ssh-rsa cd:23:45:25 end21 end22 end23
3rdline ssh-rsa ef:23:45:31 333 cde ssh-rsa ef:23:45:32 qwe rtz ssh-rsa ef:23:45:33 sedr fdert ssh-rsa ef:23:45:34 ssh-rsa ef:23:45:35
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "found_ssh_rsa="
FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims= " %%a IN (q27546207.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED found_ssh_rsa (
  IF "%%a"=="ec2:" IF "%%e"=="(RSA)" SET "data=%%c"
 ) ELSE (
  IF "%%b"=="ssh-rsa" SET "found_ssh_rsa=Y"
 )
)
ECHO data found was "%data%"
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27546207.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You say that you want the `75:d9:e3:5b:c8:17:ef:72:92:78:e5:8e:0c:82:7e:e1` from line 522 but the signal you specified was `ssh-rsa`. I'm assuming you want the data on the line following `ssh-rsa` which starts `ec2:` and ends `(RSA)` - for lack of specific information.

Comment: I simply copy/pasted your data from your `github` post to the file mentioned. What happens if you do that?

Comment: i didnt understand your comment